# Type inference and target type

Tags: java, generics

Could you explain if there is any difference between type inference and type targetting or type targeting is just type inference? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't heard about `type targeting` as a buzzword. There is type inference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you mean by "type targetting", but "target type" is a thing. From the [Java tutorial on type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html):

> The target type of an expression is the data type that the Java compiler expects depending on where the expression appears

For instance, in the statement `int a = b;`, the *target type* is `int` - the expression, `b`, should have a type of `int` (or something convertible to it), because its context requires that.

"Type inference" by contrast is a *process* used to determine the type of an expression. The target type may be used as part of the type inference process.